# Prevent View Opening Kendo

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

In my aspx, Using a Kendo Gantt, I need to prevent the opening of the view that edit the task JUST when I double click on the third column of the Gantt "Grid".

This is my JS, how can I do that?

Regards

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function (e) {
        $(".k-gantt").on("dblclick", ".k-gantt-treelist .k-grid-content tr", function () {
            var uid = $(this).attr("data-uid");
            e.preventDefault();
            if (uid) {
                $("#gantt").data("kendoGantt").editTask(uid);
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: your js looks fine to me. Can you show us what is happening

Comment: @SillyVolley in fact it's fine. I just need to prevent the opening of the edit task when I double click on the third column because the editable default reference is to the task edit but my third column should be out of it because it has just to open the resources edit not both.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude the 3rd column from triggering the function on the click event.

```
$(".k-gantt").on("dblclick", ".k-gantt-treelist .k-grid-content tr :not(td:nth-child(3))", function () {
    var uid = $(this).attr("data-uid");
    e.preventDefault();
    if (uid) {
        $("#gantt").data("kendoGantt").editTask(uid);
    }
});
```

Comment: With this code it just open the third column (resources) on double click and block the edit task (all the other column).
What I need is to prevent in this script the opening of the Task edit on the third column and just let the resources edit opening.
Gantt has as generic editable the reference to the task, that's why when I double click on the resources it open both.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with this:

```
        var currentObj = $(event.target);
        var colID = $(currentObj).closest('td').index();

        if(colID != 2) {
            if (uid) {
                $("#gantt").data("kendoGantt").editTask(uid);
            }
```